# Moving an SVN repository from one PC to another

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository for Project A in one PC with Ubuntu OS and another repository for Project B in another PC with Windows OS.

a) I would like to create a new repository with name 'Projects' in windows PC and would like to move the two projects under it and finally have a structure something like:

```
.Projects

  .projectA

    .branches
    .tags
    .trunk
  .projectB

    .branches
    .tags
    .trunk
```

b) Also, I want to restrict users accessing each project (ie, users I, J should have access to project A only...users M, N should have access to project B only...but users X, Y should be able to access both projects)

Please help me to set up this. A detailed step by step explanation is highly appreciated (I'm a novice in this).

Thanks & Regards,

Jazir

Comment: You want to keep history for both repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a)

Use [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) on each of the old repositories to put the whole repository in a portable transfer format.

Then use [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) with the `--parent-dir` parameter to load each of those dumps into your new repository at relevant paths.

b) If you run the VisualSVN software as SVN server you have built in tools to create users and set permissions on folders. If not you have to manually play with the authz-file.